# How to remove empty tables from a MySQL backup file

Tags: mysql, backup, awk

I have multiple large MySQL backup files all from different DBs and having different schemas.  I want to load the backups into our EDW but I don't want to load the empty tables.

Right now I'm cutting out the empty tables using AWK on the backup files, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

If anyone is interested, this is my AWK script:

**EDIT: I noticed today that this script has some problems, please beware if you want to actually try to use it.  Your output may be WRONG...  I will post my changes as I make them.**

```
# File: remove_empty_tables.awk
# Copyright (c) Northwestern University, 2010
# http://edw.northwestern.edu

/^--$/ {
  i = 0;
  line[++i] = $0; getline

  if ($0 ~ /-- Definition/) {
    inserts = 0;
    while ($0 !~ / ALTER TABLE .* ENABLE KEYS /) {
      # If we already have an insert:
      if (inserts > 0)
        print
      else {
        # If we found an INSERT statement, the table is NOT empty:
        if ($0 ~ /^INSERT /) {
          ++inserts
          # Dump the lines before the INSERT and then the INSERT:
          for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) print line[j]
          i = 0
          print $0
        }
        # Otherwise we may yet find an insert, so save the line:
        else line[++i] = $0
      }
      getline # go to the next line
    }
    line[++i] = $0; getline
    line[++i] = $0; getline
    if (inserts > 0) {
      for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) print line[j]
      print $0
    }
    next
  } else {
    print "--"
  }
}

{
  print
}
```

Comment: show an example of your input file. what you want to get rid or, and show desired output

Comment: could you just load the entire dump file, and then drop any empty tables ?

post-processing mysqldump files is quite tricky and fragile:  new versions often change the content surrounding the table definitions, and your script could miss these.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any option in mysqldump that would skip the empty tables in your backup. Maybe the -where option but not sure you can do sth generic. IMHO a post-treatment in a second script is not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex and perl one liners. It works by matching the `comment header + white space + start of next header.` One is for ordered dumps and the next is for non-ordered dumps.

```
perl -0777 -pi -e 's/--\s*-- Dumping data for table \`\w+\`\s*--\s*-- ORDER BY\:  [^\n]+\s+(?=--)//g' "dump.sql"
perl -0777 -pi -e 's/--\s*-- Dumping data for table \`\w+\`\s*--\n(?!--)\s*(?=--)//g' "dump.sql"
```